# powershell export to excel and perform subtotals in workbook

Tags: excel, powershell

I am creating spreadsheet to compare the hotfixes on servers that I am also using for historical record to help diagnose issues between servers.

I have downloaded [Douglas Fink's module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.3.4) that was featured by The Scripting Guys which will allow me to export-excel and it works very well.

I am writing the data to a csv, and then sorting it as I write it out to excel workbook.  This works well, but I would like to also add a subtotal based on the count of KBxxx so that if I have the total number that matches my servers, I know that all of my servers have that KB.

I am just starting with Powershell, and have never worked with writing excel.  Please help or give me some guidance.

```
$Date = Get-Date
$files = Get-ChildItem -path $PSScriptRoot\servers\*.*
$Filename = "-" + $Date.Year + "-" + $Date.Month + "-" + $Date.Day + "_" + $date.Hour + $date.Minute



    foreach ($server in $servers){
    $server
    Get-hotfix -ComputerName $server |
    Select CSName, Description,HotFixID,InstalledOn|
    Export-Csv -Path "$PSScriptRoot\output\$($file.basename)-HotFix-list-$($Filename).csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation

    }
    Import-Csv -path "$PSScriptRoot\output\$($file.basename)-HotFix-list-$($Filename).csv" | Sort-Object -Property HotFixID |Export-Excel -Path "$PSScriptRoot\output\$($file.basename)-list-$($Filename).xlsx" -WorksheetName HotFixID -Append
    #Remove-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\output\*.csv" -Force
```

If I use the subtotal command with the following settings, It totals the data by each hotfix.
[image]

I can easily see all servers queried have the top KB (1)  When I expand the Hotfix selection (2)  It shows me the remaining detail. (3)
[image]

I am learning by getting the script to run, and then adding a little more function each time.

Keith

Comment: You do a lot of writing to and reading from your hard drive. You could probably improve performance by instead saving it to a variable, then just piping that out to Excel... For that matter, `Get-Hotfix` allows you to specify multiple target computers and get the data all at once. Remove the whole `ForEach` loop and do `$Data = Get-Hotfix -ComputerName $servers` then it's just `$Data | Select CSName, Description,HotFixID,InstalledOn | Sort HotFixID | Export-Excel -Path "$PSScriptRoot\output\$($file.basename)-list-$Filename.xlsx" -WorksheetName HotFixID -Append`

Comment: As for your request, that sounds like you want help using the ImportExcel module. You may be better off asking for help at the github page for it. At the very least we would need an example of what you are looking for, maybe a screenshot with a mocked up sample.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thank you.  That shortened my Code by quite a bit.  I never knew that some CMDLETS could handle all of the data "dumped" to them in this way.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I added the images and information requested, but I thought it would actually show the images without having to follow a link. I hope this helps explain it.  -Thanks.

Comment: Try adding this to your `Export-Excel` command: `-IncludePivotTable -PivotRows HotFixID -PivotData CSName -PivotColumns CSName` see if you can live with it being a PivotTable rather than grouped like that. You may want to remove the `-PivotColumns CSName` part if you have a lot of machines.